# C++ : Overloading subscripting operator

Tags: operator-overloading, subscript

I'm implementing a vector, so i wanted it to behave as an array. That's the reason i tried to implement the subscripting operator but i haven't achieve the correct behavior.

The implementation was something like this:

```
template <typename value_type>
class Vector{ 
    private:
    value_type ** vector ; 
    long size ; 
    long usedSize ; 

    public: 
    /.../ 
    value_type & operator [] (long) ; // For writing.
    const value_type & operator [] (long) const ; // For reading.
    /.../
}

template<typename value_type> 
value_type & Vector<value_type>::operator[] ( long index ) {
    if ( index < 0 || index > usedSize ) 
        return out_of_range () ; 
    else {
        vector[index] = new value_type () ; 
        usedSize++ ; 
        return *(vector[index]) ;
    }
} 

template<typename value_type> 
const value_type & Vector<value_type>::operator[] ( long index ) const {
    if ( index < 0 || index > usedSize ) 
        return out_of_range () ; 
    else { return (*vector[index]) ; }
}
```

Then i test the behaviour of the object with this:

```
int main (void) { 
    Vector<int> * v = new Vector ( 10 ) ; // Creates a vector of 10 elements.
    (*v)[0] = 3 ; 
    int a = (*v)[0] ; 
    cout << "a = " << a << endl ;
}
```

And i get this from the execution:

```
$> a = 0
```

Some threads recommend using a handler class overloading the assignment operator, i wonder if there's anyway to avoid the use of a handler object to do the task.

Thanks in advance.

Gonzalo from Argentina.

Comment: If your `usedSize` is initialized to 0 then wouldn't any call to `operator[]` return `out_of_range()` instead of a place in your array?  What does `out_of_range()` look like?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by `cout << "a = " << 0` -- did you mean `cout << "a = " << a`?

Comment: @GuyGreer No! when ``usedSize = 0` and `index = 0` the conditional statement its false, because index is equal to usedSize not greater. out_of_range its a standard c++ exception. See it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/)

Comment: @NateKohl Yes! you're right. In my implementation it's been written properly. That's not the problem of the object misbehavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong assuming that in line

> cout << "a ="  << (*v)[0] << endl;

The

> const value_type & Vector::operator[] ( long index ) const

will be used.

In fact both times

> value_type & Vector::operator[]

is used so you "replace" previous value with new (and leaking memory at the same time)

below should help

```
value_type & Vector<value_type>::operator[] ( long index ) {
    if ( index < 0 || index > usedSize )
        ///out of bounds handling
    else {
        if(vector[index]== 0)
        {
            vector[index] = new value_type () ;
            usedSize++ ;
        }
        return *(vector[index]) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew that the problem was that `int a = (*v)[0] ;` wasn't calling the "reading" function, but i didn't realize that the was a way to solve the problem just using one method. Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: remember that return type is not a factor in overload selection. if you would make const Vector* in main - the other overload would be selected.